# (Un)register sensor listener in an Android service not always working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-sensors

I created a custom Service that listens to the devices accelerometer and I want to be able pause the sensor readings. There are two cases where I want to pause the sensor reading, first is a Pause Button in the GUI that pauses all sensors (right now I just implemented the accelerometer, but more sensors will follow), second is the sensor is specifically disabled in the app settings. I use an observable to observe changes in the App settings and Intent for the Pause button that calls the unregisterSensors() function (see code below). This works fine on the apps first run, but behavior becomes weird when I close and reopen that app. Unregistering the listener from the apps settings always works, but suddenly is does not work when using the Pause button in the GUI, even though the unregisterSensors() function is definitely called (the intent is working fine). If I force the app to quit over the Android settings or Android studio and start it again, I have normal behavior again, but not as said when just removing the app from the multi-task bar. This is relevant code of the service class:

```
class SensorService: Service(), SensorEventListener {
    private var sensorAccelerometer: Sensor? = null
    private var sensorLinearAccelerometer: Sensor? = null

    private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager


    companion object {
        var isServiceStarted = false

        var recordAccelerometer = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = true }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        sensorManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        recordAccelerometer.observeForever { value ->
            if (sensorAccelerometer != null) {
         // Always works       
         if (value) {
                    sensorAccelerometer?.also {acceleration ->
                        sensorManager.registerListener(this, acceleration, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
                    }
                    sensorLinearAccelerometer?.also { acceleration ->
                        sensorManager.registerListener(this, acceleration, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
                    }
                } else {
                    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorAccelerometer)
                    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorLinearAccelerometer)
                }
            }
        }

        isServiceStarted = true
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        // Unregister sensors
        unregisterSensors()
        isServiceStarted = false
    }

    private fun registerSensors() {
        // Register sensors
        if (availableSensors["accelerometer"]!! && recordAccelerometer.value!!) {
            sensorAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            sensorLinearAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION)

            sensorAccelerometer?.also {acceleration ->
                sensorManager.registerListener(this, acceleration, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
            }
            sensorLinearAccelerometer?.also { acceleration ->
                sensorManager.registerListener(this, acceleration, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
            }
        }
    }


    private fun unregisterSensors() {
        // Unregister sensors
        // Works not after closing and opening the app
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorAccelerometer)
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorLinearAccelerometer)
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        // Stop service unless sensors are being recorded
        stopSelf(1)
    }
}
```

Anybody might have an idea what the issue is? I cannot see any difference in calling the sensorManager.unregisterListener(...) that could cause this issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue registering a bluetooth lte beause when scanner detects device it triggers serveral times so I was registering the device several times. I don't know if this situation can suffer with an acelerometer. I got crazy to solve the bluetooth problem.

Comment: You are right, sorry for the spam answer. I didn't see any mistakes in your code, so I made an assumption.

Comment: I think you should check very carefully, at runtime, to make sure that the `SensorEventListener` being passed to `unregisterListener()` is the same one that is passed to `registerListener`. I can't help but suspect that you've got two `Services` going somehow, and that two are registered, but only one unregisters. Btw, how exactly do you know the sensor events continue?

Comment: @greeble31 Found a solution now (see below), the problem were indeed different instances of the service. Not exactly sure what you mean with the last question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in case someone from the future has the same problem, I found a solution now. The problem was that I bind to this service in my activity, and bound services return a new instance every time you bind to it. Therefore indeed different event listeners were used as @greeble31 already assumed. Since I need to bind to the service, I use LiveData now register/unregister a sensor.

```
accelerometerRegistered.observeForever { value ->
    if (value) {
        sensorAccelerometer?.also {acceleration ->
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, acceleration, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
        }
    } else {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, sensorAccelerometer)
    }
}
```

The LiveData object is defined in the companion object so I can alter it from in and outside the Service class.

Comment: Glad you fixed this, and I was just about to upvote, but two things bothers me: If you get two different instances of a `Service`, there should have been on `onDestroy()` in-between (which means you unregistered). IOW, you should only get a new instance for each bind _if the previous service was destroyed_.

Comment: The service is destroyed when I remove the task( unless the sensors are being recorded; I have two state: listening and recording, recording means the sensor data will be saved when the recording is stopped). That is why I get a new instance on the next start (unless recording is active).